# How to write a function that takes an argument and adds it to an array?

Tags: javascript, function

I'm trying writing a function that takes an argument the user inputs into the console, adds it to the array and returns it. 
This is my code.

```
function Album(){
  this.listPhotos=["bee", "ladybug", "caterpillar", "ant"];
  this.addPhoto = function(x){
  listPhotos.push("x");
  console.log (x.listPhotos);
  }
}
```

Comment: ...and the problem is?

Comment: It should be `this.listPhotos.push`

Comment: Btw, what's the problem? `(:`

Comment: `x` probably shouldn't be a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few things wrong:

1. `listPhotos.push` should be `this.listPhotos.push`
2. You should be pushing the variable `x` and not the string `x`
3. When logging you want `this.listPhotos` and not `x.listPhotos`

```js
function Album() {
  this.listPhotos = ["bee", "ladybug", "caterpillar", "ant"];
  this.addPhoto = function(x) {
    this.listPhotos.push(x);
    console.log(this.listPhotos);
  }
}

let a = new Album()
a.addPhoto('123')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference the array that's the *property of the instantiated object*. In your code, the plain variable `listPhotos` isn't declared anywhere.

Use `this` to reference the calling context of the current function (which, in this situation, is the instantiated object):

```js
function Album(){
  this.listPhotos=["bee", "ladybug", "caterpillar", "ant"];
  this.addPhoto = function(x){
    this.listPhotos.push(x);
    console.log(this.listPhotos);
  }
}
const myAlbum = new Album();
myAlbum.addPhoto("anotherphoto");
```

Another option is to declare the array as a standalone variable *inside the object* (not as a property of the object), but you have to make sure you don't mix up the two methods:

```js
function Album(){
  const listPhotos=["bee", "ladybug", "caterpillar", "ant"];
  this.addPhoto = function(x){
    listPhotos.push(x);
    console.log(listPhotos);
  }
}
const myAlbum = new Album();
myAlbum.addPhoto("anotherphoto");
```

Comment: Your not making use of the param `x`

Comment: Oh, so I'm guessing `x` was intended to be the item that gets pushed to the array, rather than just a placeholder string. Thanks, edited